# Change Data Capture without the help of power exchange

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, cdc, informatica-powerexchange

We utilise PowerExchange mostly because the unique key combination may change, and we want to know what exactly happened by comparing the record to its previous version.

Ex: Id, Name, and Location make up the table's unique key combination.
The records on the table today might be 1, Sharukh, Mumbai.
It can be changed to 1, Sharukh, Delhi tomorrow.

Powerexchange is being used for the CDC process and has the ability to store the previous version of the record and let us know when the unique key combination changes through a flag.

I would like to introduce a similar logic(through any ETL or ELT tools) and maintain the table in snowflake without the help of powerexcahnge

Can somebody tell me if there is a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Have a look at Snowflake’s Streams and Tasks capabilities